# Data sharing over WiFi

Tags: android, bitmap, wifi

I have establish WiFi connection between two android devices. Now I want to send Bitmap from server to client. I use the following code to send Bitmap from server to Client:

server code:

```
            outputStream = hostThreadSocket.getOutputStream();

            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20,stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            String str =Base64.encodeToString(byteArray,0);
            msgReply+="  "+str;

            outputStream.write(str.getBytes());
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
```

client code:

```
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream =
                    new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int bytesRead;
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
            }

           byte[]    temp_arr = new byte[1024];
           String[] safe = response.split("=");
           try{
               temp_arr=Base64.decode(safe[0], 0);
           }catch (Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           Bitmap bmp =    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(temp_arr,0,temp_arr.length);
           ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);
           img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```